# Query to pull main items based on characteristics of its sub item?

Tags: sql, subquery

Sorry about the wording of the title if it didn't make sense.

I have a table containing orders and order items. I pulled a small order to allow you to see what I am referring to.

[image: Sample Data]

When looking at the attachment:

- [Order Number] is just the order number
- [Unique ID] is the unique ID assigned to each item within the order.
- [Asm Main] represents if the item is a main item or a sub
  item.
- [Asm Num] is the number that links sub items to its main
  item. (both the sub and main item will have the same [Asm Num])
- [Item Number] was selected to make it easier to understand how
  main/sub items are linked.
- [Date Promised] and [Ship Date] are the two dates I need to focus on.

Here's what I'm trying to do. I want to the pull the main items when:

- the main item has a [Date Promised] field that IS NULL
- and ALL the sub items for that main item have [Ship Date] that IS NOT NULL.

*Clarification Update:* When Asm Main=0, I need the ship date to be NOT null. When Asm Main=1, ship date doesn't matter, I just need Date Promised to be null.

```
    SELECT bo.[Order Number],boi.[Unique ID]
    from [Booked Order Items] boi JOIN [Booked Orders] bo ON boi.[Order Number] = bo.[Order Number] 
    WHERE boi.[Asm Main]=1 AND boi.[Date Promised] IS NULL
```

I can clearly do the first step, but for getting **only** the main items that have **ALL** of their sub items having not null ship dates along with the condition above, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be MySQL code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same logic as yours for the JOIN of two table, take Main items(along with `Asm Num`) in query A. Apply similar logic for sub-items in query B by taking count of those sub-items with `Ship Date` as `IS NULL` and if the count is more than 0 it means you don't want that main item with the corresponding `Asm Num` because all sub-items must have `Ship Date` as `NOT NULL` based on your requirements. Hence the condition `and B.[sub_items_null_dates] = 0` while joining `A` and `B`.

```
select A.[Order Number], A.[Unique ID]
from
(   select bo.[Order Number], boi.[Unique ID], boi.[Asm Num]
    from
    [Booked Order Items] boi JOIN [Booked Orders] bo
    on boi.[Order Number] = bo.[Order Number]
    where boi.[Asm Main] = 1 and boi.[Date Promised] IS NULL
) A
JOIN
(   select bo.[Order Number], boi.[Asm Num],
    SUM(CASE WHEN boi.[Ship Date] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as sub_items_null_dates
    from    
    [Booked Order Items] boi JOIN [Booked Orders] bo
    on boi.[Order Number] = bo.[Order Number]
    where boi.[Asm Main] = 0
    GROUP BY bo.[Order Number], boi.[Asm Num]
) B
ON A.[Order Number] = B.[Order Number] 
and A.[Asm Num] = B.[Asm Num]
and B.[sub_items_null_dates] = 0;
```

Comment: This was perfect! I have it completed now! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted the orders, I would go with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT bo.*
FROM [Booked Orders] bo
WHERE bo.[Date Promised] IS NULL AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [Booked Order Items] boi
                  WHERE boi.[Order Number] = bo.[Order Number]  AND
                        boi.[Ship Date] IS NULL
                 );
```

(I'm not clear how the ASM number fits in.)

If you are using MySQL, you can get the items by doing:

```
SELECT boi.*
FROM [Booked Order Items] boi JOIN
     [Booked Orders] bo
     ON boi.[Order Number] = bo.[Order Number] 
WHERE bo.[Date Promised] IS NULL AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [Booked Order Items] boi2
                  WHERE boi2.[Order Number] = bo.[Order Number]  AND
                        boi2.[Ship Date] IS NULL
                 )
```

Comment: The Asm Number is going to be the same number for the main item and all of the sub items that go with it. For example, If I wanted to pull an item and the parts that need to go with it, I can just search that Asm Number and it'll pull up the main item and it's subs. The problem which what your showing me is that. When Asm Main=0, I need the ship date to be not null. When Asm Main=1, ship date doesn't matter, I just need Date Promised to be null.